# Darksiders 3 stuck at The Scar how to get out

Tags: darksiders-3

During backtracking the game, I got stuck in The Scar.

This is the place I got stuck:

[image]

Another view:

[image]

And a final view which points out my issue pretty good:

[image]

As you can see in the 3rd picture, the shutter should open. This is no longer true for me because I

> destroyed the storm.

Now arises the question, how do I get out without loosing anything? I would prefer to simply climb out so I can keep going from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some point I just quit the game and was then set back to some previous save point, but lost no items/souls etc. I just had to walk walk there again.

Also as of a newer patch, there is a menu option which sets you back to the latest save point without losing stuff (probably for exactly these kind of situations).